# Laravel SoftDelete query not work

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I'm using Laravel 5.

My Code is

```
DB::table('users')->where('is_active',0)
                  ->where('created_at','<','NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY')
                  ->delete();
```

I want to delete unactivated users older than 48 hours, but my code does not work. Why not?

Comment: What's error you are getting?

Comment: I got no error, but users still in database

Comment: What happens when you `dd(DB::table('users')->where('is_active',0)
                  ->where('created_at','<','NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY')->get())` ?

Comment: A `soft delete` doesn't remove the data from your DB, it simply places a flag on a column that says the data is *"deleted"* so to speak.

Comment: I got all inactive users, older and newer

Comment: Do you want to actually DELETE the data (permanently gone from your database) OR SoftDelete?

Comment: Can you update your question with the above result from `dd()` ?

Comment: resolved by this  
The where method quotes the value passed as the second parameter, so your second SQL condition will become:

created_at < `NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY`
Instead of:

created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
Which means no rows will be matched. Instead you should use whereRaw to avoid the value being quoted:

DB::table('users')->where('is_active', 0)
                  ->whereRaw('created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY')
                  ->delete();

Answer (score 0):

The `where` method quotes the value passed as the second parameter, so your second SQL condition will become:

```sql
created_at < `NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY`
```

Instead of:

```sql
created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

Which means no rows will be matched. Instead you should use `whereRaw` to avoid the value being quoted:

```php
DB::table('users')->where('is_active', 0)
                  ->whereRaw('created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY')
                  ->delete();
```

You can read more about this in the [Advanced Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses) Laravel Documentation.